# Retrieve HTML from DNN through the API

Tags: api, dotnetnuke

I would like to retrieve HTML content from DNN through the API for an entire page for an anonymous or authenticated user. This content will include all the content for the page, including menu items, etc.

To illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish, I can fake this by instantiating a browser and navigating to the page, harvesting the HTML from the browser. However, I would like to retrieve this from the API directly to improve the performance. Also, I would like to do this all in the context of the user.

Thanks for any help.

--Mark

Comment: This is not something you will be able to find an answer to here on StackOverflow, and I highly doubt the DNN API itself has any methods exposed that would do this outside of at the module level, and even at the module level you'd be hard pressed as different modules have their own API.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way that DNN pieces together the content on a module-by-module basis, within each pane.  And the fact that the skin is a separate piece and it has individual skin objects that render object-by-object.

There is not an API that will do this.  ALl of this logic, to a certain point is contained within default.aspx, but you would be seriously reinventing the wheel trying to do this.

If you need the full HTML, with all skin elements etc.  The fastest way is to use an `HttpWebRequest` to make the call.  It is super fast, and would be far more stable version to version.

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently using System.Net.WebClient to pull content from DNN page out through the WebAPI. But HttpWebRequest might allow me to do authentication in a little more fine-grained fashion. I will eventually want to pass the user's credentials through SAML somehow to DNN. I'm looking to do this:

1. User hits my MVC app
2. My MVC app hits DNN's WebAPI
3. The WebAPI hits the DNN API (or HttpWebRequest or WebClient or ...)
4. The content is returned to my app to pull around itself like a visual wrapper.